# Check the index of a list within a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have the following list in python:

```
listx = [array([-1.67457473, -0.13608048]), array([ 2.62527567, -2.06095641]), array([-1.54613966, -0.55125153]), array([ 1.10801579,  2.28617014]), array([-1.2743137 , -0.70983752]), array([ 0.76173662,  1.17195581])]
```

I want to check the index of this item within the list:

```
item = [ 1.10801579,  2.28617014]
```

When I use the normal index check method:

```
index = listx.index(item)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any idea how to get around this problem?

Comment: Please note, `item = [ 1.10801579,  2.28617014]` is not in your list, since that `item` is a *list* whereas your list contains `numpy.ndarray` objects.

Comment: So, one solution: `[i for i,e in enumerate(listx) if np.array_equal(e, item)]` which will return a list of indices.